# why a set returns unordered values even since it implements a HashMap internally?

Tags: java, collections

can anyone tell me why a set returns unordered values even since it implements a HashMap internally ? By ordered i meant, why does a set not return the values in the same order in which they were added

Comment: Why would a `HashMap` return ordered values? Ordered by _what_?

Comment: A HashMap is unordered.

Comment: but you always get values in the same order you entered them but not in sets

Comment: Right, why would you think it should behave otherwise?

Comment: @EkanshRastogi *you always get values in the same order you entered them but not in set*. **No**, you don't.

Comment: @EkanshRastogi that's not true. You need a `LinkedHashMap` for that.

Comment: They're not returned in the order they're added because they're added to a hashtable.  Google the term -- there's certainly a good Wikipedia article or some such where you will learn how it works.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, i just goofed up a few things here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) for getting the elements in the order they were added when iterating over the elements of the Set.

> public class `LinkedHashSet<E>`
>   extends `HashSet<E>`
>   implements `Set<E>`, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for `HashMap`:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Which makes sense, since explicit ordering isn't how hash tables work.

There's also this in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for the iterator of `Set`:

> The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

These classes don't guarantee ordering.  It's documented that way, and their implementations don't imply ordering.  (Again, that's not how hash tables work.)

Answer (score 0):

Hashmaps aren't ordered (by the order they were added) internally. Moreover, the addition of a new element may entirely change the ordering of the elements in a hashmap internally, if a rehash was caused.

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps are not ordered in their implementation. You may want to use a TreeMap, which is ordered internally (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).